# Starting webdriver from protractor configuration file fails to start

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

If I start webdriver externally and point protractor to the URL, my protractor tests run just fine.

If I set up protractor to start up my webdriver server with:

```
  seleniumServerJar: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar',
  chromeDriver: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
```

then the tests fail with

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
Selenium standalone server started at http://X.X.X.X:37711/wd/hub

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1539
      var result = fn();
                   ^
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {"message":"Can't find variable: angular","name":"ReferenceError","line":4,"stack":"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular\n    at :4\n    at anonymous (:9)\n    at Na (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():14)\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():15\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():15\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16","stackArray":[{"sourceURL":"","line":4},{"sourceURL":"","line":9,"function":"anonymous"},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":14,"function":"Na"},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":15},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":15},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":16},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":16},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":16}],"sourceId":140630251385168}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1412:15
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1561:7
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1243:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1539:20)
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:362:12)
    at notifyAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:331:7)
    at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:309:7)
    at reject [as errback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:439:5)
    at reject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1725:5)
```

Any ideas what might cause this issue?

Comment: Open issue here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/822